# Showing fullsize grid image in image view is blurry

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

I have a grid of view pictures captured from camera or taken from gallery. When I click on the grid view item to make it display the full-size image in the imageview activity, the image is blurry.

This is how my grid looks

```
    <GridView 
      android:id ="@+id/grid_view"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:numColumns="auto_fit"
      android:columnWidth="80dp"
      android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
      android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
      android:paddingLeft="1dp"
      android:paddingRight="1dp"
      android:paddingTop="1dp"
      android:paddingBottom="1dp"
      android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
```

The Adapter class getView () that feeds the data to grid looks like this

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //create new image view to show the thumbnail
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext); //create a new imageview in the context thats passed (ie., mainView)

    Contact picture = data.get(position);
    byte[] img = picture._image; //get the bytes out of Contact
    ByteArrayInputStream imgStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(img);
    Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imgStream);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(theImage);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200,200));
    return imageView;
}
```

and the activity where I show the image in full-size has the following xml

```
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">        

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:layout_weight="50"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:text="Share"
            android:layout_weight="50"/>

    </LinearLayout> 

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fullimageView"
         android:src="@drawable/facebook"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       />

</LinearLayout>
```

I believe fill_parent makes the image looks blurry. But if I give specific numbers for width and height, it looks smaller or really huge, but not the right dimension where its clear and is exactly same as what was clicked in camera or chosen in gallery. How to restore it to right size.

Comment: Problem doesn't lay in the adapter, nor the XMl file. It's the way and the object you are retrieving for the picture.

Comment: Can u be more specific please? what object should I be retrieving instead? If not byte array input stream then what way can i retieve?

Comment: Without the code for it, it's impossible to tell. My best guess it's that scaling after retrieving the image is being affected. Where from you are getting it how you are setting it to a view, if you are getting it from a view. It's up in the air.

Comment: Hi, showing the full size image is set as another activity and to set the bitmap in that activity this is what am doing                           
  Intent i = getIntent();
  //get the bitmap
  theImage = (Bitmap)i.getParcelableExtra("imagename");
  imageId = i.getExtras().getInt("imageid");
  imgDetail.setImageBitmap(theImage);

Comment: I figured it out myself. Please visit https://github.com/Orange1987 for my solution